# Update Google Calendar Event TimeZone with PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I must be missing something in the api docs, how do I update a Google event timezone via an api request?

```
 $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
 $event = $service->events->get($calendarId, $eventId);
 $event->setSummary($summary);
 $service->events->update($calendarId, $event->getId(), $event);

 $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
 $start->setDateTime($dateTimeStr);

 $event->setStart($start);
 $event->setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
```

The error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "setTimezone" of class "Google_Service_Calendar_Event". (500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: have you tried https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/update?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the timezone on the calendar itself. Don't set it on the event.

See the examples in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/update):

```
$calendar = $service->calendars->get('primary');

$calendar->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

$updatedCalendar = $service->calendars->update('primary', $calendar);
```